How to access locally saved credential data of a user from the SYSTEM context?
I am building an application that requires deletion of saved credentials (Web credentials, windows credentials saved within credential manager) of a user. My process is running in the SYSTEM context.
I am trying to use the regular CredMan WinAPI, CredEnumerate and CredRead to accomplish the same but unable to enumerate through the credentials.
When I run the same piece of code in the user's context, I am able to access the credentials. This leads me to believe that SYSTEM account does not have the required access privileges for those credential objects?
Important to Note: We are talking about deceptive credentials here that I am injecting for each of the users, so I am open to adding any specific type of security descriptor for these credentials.
Ran LaZagne tool locally : 7 credentials found
Ran LaZagne tool using PSExec in SYSTEM context using "psexec -s" : 0 Credentials Found
Want to retrieve the credential set of all users, but failed to do so. Is there a security descriptor of sorts that I will have to add to the credentials ?? (As these credentials are initially injected by me).
Limitations: I can't spin a thread in the user's context as I don't have the user credentials.
Unfair Advantages: The credentials are initially injected by our process, so I can make changes to the way that is done.
Is there a way to access the user's credential context from the system account?
Couldn't find any resource on this on the web, and new to Windows development.

SYSTEM account does not have the required access privileges for those credential objects - no. but credentials - where thay saved, how it encrypted - depend from user sid in the token. different users have different sids, location for credentials, different master key, etc. so for access concrete user credentials you need impersonate this user - set it token on self thread. if you this during handle request from user - this is trivial - you simply impersonate caller.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@FerryTo I think this is more of a theoretical question pertaining to Windows internals.

@RbMm I would like a workaround that does not involve impersonation or having to deal with user credentials at all.

Have you read https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2021/05/dumping-stored-credentials-with.html?m=1 and the linked Mimikatz site?
